# Does it make sense or is it possible to write a `iter` function for lazy list?

Tags: ocaml

Say we have such a lazy list:

```
type 'a lazy_list_t = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazy_list_t)
```

Does it make sense to have a function like the `iter` in regular list:

```
val iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit

List.iter f [a1; ...; an] applies function f in turn to a1; ...; an. It is equivalent to begin f a1; f a2; ...; f an; () end.
```

Or is it possible to produce `iter_lazy` like

```
val iter_lazy: ('a -> unit) -> 'a lazy_list -> unit
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not make much sense.

First, and you probably noticed it, all your list are infinite (you do not have an empty element). So, only examples of inhabitant of your type are somehow using a recursive function, eg. :

```
let omega = 
  let rec f n = Cons (n, fun () -> f (n + 1)) in
  f 0
```

This implements the infinite stream [ 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

If you WANT a diverging program you could implement :

```
let rec iter f (Cons (n, g)) = f n; iter f (g ())
```

but if you do `iter print_int omega` it will result output all integers which will take some time.

So itering is not an option. What would work is "mapping", you can implement the function :

```
val map:  ('a -> 'b) -> 'a lazy_list_t -> 'b lazy_list
let rec map f (Cons (x, g)) = Cons (f x, fun () -> map f (g ()))
```

Notice how the recursive call to map is "protected" by the "fun () ->" so it will not trigger "right away" but only each time the tail of your lazy list is forced.

You can use this to lazily compute on infinite streams, eg :

```
let evens = map ((*) 2) omega
```

computes the stream [0; 2; 4; 6; 8; ...

Note, that you could use it to implement some sort of "iter" by mapping a function that does a side_effect eg.

```
let units = map print_int evens
```

will output right away the number "0" and outputs the stream [(); (); (); ... and each time you force one of the "tail" of this stream it will output the corresponding number (it can happen multiple times). Example:

```
(* Force the tail *)
val tl : 'a lazy_list_t -> 'a lazy_list_t
let tl (Cons (_, g)) = g ()

let () = begin
  tl units; (* ouputs "2" *)
  tl (tl units); (* outputs "24" *)
  tl units;  (* outputs "2" *)
end
```

(I haven't tried the code so there may be some typos).